# Prim’s algorithm and MST

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

How can I describe a family of graphs with V vertices and E edges for which the worst-case running of the priority-queue implementation of Prim’s algorithm is confirmed?

Answer (score 0):

Well, without knowing exactly what the particular implementation looks like it's hard to say, but if I recall correctly for Prim's you always need to check Θ(E) edges while determining the MST. If the priority queue is implemented as a binary heap (which is the standard way), then each "check" is O(log V), so the worst case running time of O(E * log V) always happens.

Comment: Thanks, the priority queue is implemented as a binary heap